# How I can write reverse alphabet with not using reverse code?

Tags: c#

A..Z
and reversed
Z..A 
How I can?

I was try this:

```
char i; 
for (i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: What does *"without using reverse code"* mean?

Comment: Please, be more specific on your questions as we like to help. Your questions looks very bad as we can see no research of your own has been made.

Comment: Just need write like this
A..Z
and             
B..Z

We can't use array.reverse string [A..Z] & [Z..A]

Comment: Put values to stack in foreach, then do Stack.Pop() while Stack is not empty

Answer (score 3):

Just flip your conditions around:

```
char i; 
for (i = 'Z'; i >= 'A'; i--)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```